# Flutter : Sort widget according to a sorted list of values

Tags: dart, flutter

I currently have an app that displays nearby hospitals within a 1.5 km radius and it looks like this:

[image: List of Hospitals]

The trouble I am having is that I could not figure out how to sort the card based on their calculated distance from lowest to highest.

I made a `List<double> doubleList = [];` to store the list of calculated distances and sorted it with `doubleList.sort();`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 return new ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: jsonresponse.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){

                  String name = jsonresponse[index]["Name"];
                  String lat = jsonresponse[index]["Latitude"];
                  String lng = jsonresponse[index]["Longitude"];

                  var distance = new GreatCircleDistance.fromDegrees(latitude1: double.parse(widget.lat), longitude1: double.parse(widget.lng), latitude2: double.parse(lat), longitude2: double.parse(lng));

                  var totaldistance = distance.haversineDistance().toStringAsFixed(2);

                  double distanceDouble = double.parse(totaldistance);

                  if(distanceDouble < 1500.00){

                    doubleList.add(distanceDouble);

                    doubleList.sort((a, b){
                      return a.compareTo(b);
                    });

                    print(doubleList);

                    return new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Card(
                          child: new ListTile(
                            title: new Text(name),
                            subtitle: new Text("$distanceDouble m away"),
                            trailing: new IconButton(
                                icon: new Icon(Icons.info),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  makeDialog(lat, lng);
                                }),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }else{
                    return new Container();
                  }
                });
```

This is the output of the sorted distance values when printed:

```
I/flutter ( 4286): [987.8]
I/flutter ( 4286): [987.8, 1014.87]
I/flutter ( 4286): [987.8, 1014.87, 1352.22]
I/flutter ( 4286): [128.26, 987.8, 1014.87, 1352.22]
I/flutter ( 4286): [128.26, 987.8, 1014.87, 1260.73, 1352.22]
I/flutter ( 4286): [122.91, 128.26, 987.8, 1014.87, 1260.73, 1352.22]
I/flutter ( 4286): [122.91, 128.26, 987.8, 1014.87, 1260.73, 1303.36, 1352.22]
I/flutter ( 4286): [122.91, 128.26, 987.8, 1014.87, 1232.47, 1260.73, 1303.36, 1352.22]
I/flutter ( 4286): [122.91, 128.26, 987.8, 1014.87, 1232.47, 1232.47, 1260.73, 1303.36, 1352.22]
```

**My question is:**

How do I make sure the widget will follow the order of the sorted distance values?

Answer (score 6):

`ListView.builder` is taking an itemBuilder wich is responsible of building one item. careful here, your sorting each time you build an item.

You need to sort your `jsonresponse` before calling `List.builder` or `jsonresponse[index]` won't be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your input in this matter, Hadrien. I will try sorting it before calling Listview.Builder.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
jsonresponse.sort((a, b) {
  var distance1 = new GreatCircleDistance.fromDegrees(latitude1: double.parse(widget.lat), longitude1: double.parse(widget.lng), latitude2: double.parse(a.lat), longitude2: double.parse(a.lng));
  var totaldistance1 = distance1.haversineDistance().toStringAsFixed(2);
  double distanceDouble1 = double.parse(totaldistance1);
  var distance2 = new GreatCircleDistance.fromDegrees(latitude1: double.parse(widget.lat), longitude1: double.parse(widget.lng), latitude2: double.parse(b.lat), longitude2: double.parse(b.lng));
  var totaldistance2 = distance2.haversineDistance().toStringAsFixed(2);
  double distanceDouble2 = double.parse(totaldistance2);
  return (distanceDouble1 - distanceDouble2).toInt();
});
```

before return new Column (I set toInt because double is not suitable for comparator)

Comment: it should be checked answer (y)

Comment: Hi sir, I used the settlement method for this before.
do you know how to set max radius for sort distance? [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033034/flutter-set-the-max-radius-when-displaying-the-list-distance)

Comment: You can check the answer