# flutter - Set the max radius when displaying the List distance

Tags: list, dart, flutter, location, distance

I am developing the nearest Food Dish application location. I managed to display it based on the location closest to the user, using this plugin [great_circle_distance](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/great_circle_distance#-readme-tab-)

I want to know how to set the max radius? ex. < 30 Km

Here my code:

```
 _foodByCategories.sort((a, b) {
      var distance1 = new GreatCircleDistance.fromDegrees(
          latitude1:
              model.userLocation == null ? 0.0 : model.userLocation["latitude"],
          longitude1: model.userLocation == null
              ? 0.0
              : model.userLocation["longitude"],
          latitude2: a.lat,
          longitude2: a.long);
      double totaldistance1 = distance1.haversineDistance();

      var distance2 = new GreatCircleDistance.fromDegrees(
          latitude1:
              model.userLocation == null ? 0.0 : model.userLocation["latitude"],
          longitude1: model.userLocation == null
              ? 0.0
              : model.userLocation["longitude"],
          latitude2: b.lat,
          longitude2: b.long);
      double totaldistance2 = distance2.haversineDistance();
      return (totaldistance1 - totaldistance2).toInt();
    });
```

Any answer will appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correct

```
_foodByCategories.where((a) {
  var distance = new GreatCircleDistance.fromDegrees(latitude1: double.parse(widget.lat), longitude1: double.parse(widget.lng), latitude2: double.parse(a.lat), longitude2: double.parse(a.lng));
  var totaldistance = distance.haversineDistance().toStringAsFixed(2);
  double distanceDouble1 = double.parse(totaldistance);
  return distance <= 30000; // or something like that
}).sort ... // and your sorting code
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any way to do this within the package you are using. You could suggest to the developer to add this functionality in?

Alternatively, you are getting the `total distance` in your code so you could just do a simple `if statement` to check if the total distance is greater than your set max radius.

Comment: Unfortunately the developer is no longer developing this plugin.

I have agreed but the result of `totalDistance1 - totalDistance 2 < 30` but its return a boolean value

Comment: Do you mean you need it to return you a boolean?

Comment: I need to return to Int..
(see after `totalDistance1 - totalDistance2` for sorting, then i convert it `to.Int()` )

Comment: Use `_foodByCategories.where()` before you sort. Move your distance calculation to a separate function outside.    `_foodByCategories.where(/* calculate distances and filter in distance_diff < 30*/ ).sort( /* calculate distances and sort by distance_diff */ );`